# Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: mysql

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have added mysql in requirements.yaml. Helm dependency downloads the mysql chart

```
helm dependency update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "nginx" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository

Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading mysql from repo <our private repository>
Deleting outdated charts
```

But when I do helm install my_app_chart ../my_app_chart
It gives error

```
Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: mysql
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I updated .helmignore

```
# Patterns to ignore when building packages.
# This supports shell glob matching, relative path matching, and
# negation (prefixed with !). Only one pattern per line.
.DS_Store
# Common VCS dirs
.git/
.gitignore
.bzr/
.bzrignore
.hg/
.hgignore
.svn/
# Common backup files
*.swp
*.bak
*.tmp
*~
# Various IDEs
.project
.idea/
*.tmproj
.vscode/
charts/
```

It contained charts/ I removed the entry and it worked

```
# Patterns to ignore when building packages.
# This supports shell glob matching, relative path matching, and
# negation (prefixed with !). Only one pattern per line.
.DS_Store
# Common VCS dirs
.git/
.gitignore
.bzr/
.bzrignore
.hg/
.hgignore
.svn/
# Common backup files
*.swp
*.bak
*.tmp
*~
# Various IDEs
.project
.idea/
*.tmproj
.vscode/
```

Comment: Just so it helps others, I had `*.tgz` in .helmignore

Comment: Confirming what @AshvjitSingh said. I also had `*.tgz` and could not run `helm package .` until I removed it. I also don't have `charts/` in `.helmignore`.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.

Comment: This is a wrong way of doing it *.tgz should never be pushed in. You must adjust your chart as shown by @Affes Salem then perform helm dependency update as should by PhoneixS.

Answer (score 110):

You don't have to add it to the control version system, you just download them again if for some reason you have lost them (for example when you clone the repository). To do this, execute the command:

`helm dependency update`

The above command will download the dependencies you've defined in the `requirements.yaml` file or `dependencies` entry in `Chart.yaml` to the `charts` folder. This way, requirements are updated and you'll have the correct dependencies without worrying about if you updated them also in the control version system.

Comment: Remember to run this after 'cd' ing into your helm chart dir. Else it might throw an error like: Error: validation: chart.metadata is required

Comment: I have the same issue in `helm install --set cp-zookeeper.enabled=false,cp-zookeeper.url="unhinged-robin-cp-zookeeper-headless:2181" cp-helm-charts/charts/cp-kafka`. I have removed requirements.yaml. and it solved

Answer (score 6):

I have encountred the same error message when I first started learning how to use libcharts, I used `chart.yaml` to specify the dependency of the libchart like so:

**chart.yaml**

```yaml
...
dependencies:
  - name: mylibchart
    version: 0.1.0
    repository: file://path/to/libchart
```

and in that libchart **chart.yaml** data was like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: lib <-- this was causing the error to occur (should be mylibchart instead)
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: library
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

so as you can see the name specified in the dependencies has to be the same name of the chart/libchart.

Comment: Thanks @Affes Salem. This is exactly the issue I had and its hard to diagnose since the error and even debugging give no clues to this.

Comment: Glad that helped, also starting working with chart dependencies, make sure to try things test and troubleshoot by yourself on a separate dir/new_project to get an idea about what's going on (that's the approach I follow using helm), you can also find more in the [helm_dependency docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/)