# while trying to deploy Prometheus I got Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: kube-state-metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, helm3

Commands used:

```
git clone https://github.com/helm/charts.git
```

---

```
cd charts/stable/prometheus
```

---

```
helm install prometheus . --namespace monitoring --set rbac.create=true
```

After Running the 3rd command I got below error:

[image]

Anyone Please help me out from this issue...

Thanks...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210148/error-found-in-chart-yaml-but-missing-in-charts-directory-mysql)

Comment: no not worked for me

Comment: On the [GitHub page you can see that](https://github.com/helm/charts): "This project is no longer supported.". Did you try another methods of installation, like [this one](https://k21academy.com/docker-kubernetes/prometheus-grafana-monitoring/)?

Answer (score 1):

On the [GitHub page](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus#prometheus) you can see that this repo it deprecated:

> DEPRECATED and moved to https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts

So I'd recommend to add and use [Prometheus Community Kubernetes Helm Charts](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts) repository:

```
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
```

Then you can install Prometheus with your flags using following command:

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus --namespace monitoring --set rbac.create=true
```

If you really want to stick to the version from the old repository, you don't have to clone repo to your host. Just [follow steps from the repository page](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus#prometheus). Make sure you have `https://charts.helm.sh/stable` repository added to the helm by running `helm repo list`. If not, add it using command:

```
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

Then, you can install your chart:

```
helm install prometheus stable/prometheus --namespace monitoring --set rbac.create=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to install the **state metrics** you can try

To disable the dependency during installation, set `kubeStateMetrics.enabled` to **false** into **values.yaml** file

in **values.yaml** file line no. [435](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/2cacc16807caedc6cabf1606db27e0d78c844564/charts/prometheus/values.yaml#L435) change **false**

Once done with editing the file, you run the same command.

```
helm install prometheus . --namespace monitoring --set rbac.create=true
```

Ref document : https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus#dependencies

**OR**

You can try the

1. git clone https://github.com/helm/charts.git
2. cd charts/stable/prometheus
3. helm dependency update

Try running above command in `kube-state-metrics` folder if exist

4. helm install prometheus . --namespace monitoring --set rbac.create=true

You need to install the dependency of prometheus also

Read more at : https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/README.md#dependencies